# django update query is not working but works in shell

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a function in django , it's work well but queryset model not update

```
def SLATarget(instanceID):
    SLAstatus = 2
    print(SLAstatus)
    print(instanceID)
    ProcessInstance.objects.filter(no=instanceID).update(SLAstate=SLAstatus)
```

model:

```
SLAoprators=[
  (0, 'in target'),
  (1, 'in milestone'),
  (2, 'Exceded milestone'),
  (3, 'Exceded target'),
  ]

class ProcessInstance(models.Model):
    no = models.CharField('NO.', max_length=100, blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_on = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    SLAstate = models.IntegerField(choices=SLAoprators,blank=True,null=True)
```

run in another class and function not update model but when call in shell it's work

```
SLATarget("1221")
```

result of print is

2

1221

Comment: can you paste `ProcessInstance` model class, please?

Comment: it's so strength when i call it in another function/class it shown print result but object not update , when i run it in shell object updated include print values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve issue by change format of model from integer to Charfield choicefield . Django version is 3.1